# How to call a task inside another gradle task

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

```
task buildJars(dependsOn:buildFlag) {
doLast{
if (tasks.buildFlag.bf=='T')
 {
build.finalizedBy("taskA")
}
else
{
build.finalizedBy("taskB")
}
}
}
```

I am not able execute taskA/TaskB based on above condition.

Comment: NOTE: I am able to print some values inside if/else conditions but not able to execute a task

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this way doesn't work. You have to define finalization outside a task:

```
task task1{

}

task task2{

}

def condition=true

if(condition)
    build.finalizedBy(task1)
else
    build.finalizedBy(task2)
```

Comment: Yeah, But the issue is flag "tasks.buildFlag.bf=='T'" is getting set in a task and which can be accessed by depensOn task. Is there is any way where variable set inside a task can be accessed outside task ?. I tried setting ext.var could not help